# Alfresco Group task not working

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

```
I have group name manager. I want assign task to that group. The assignment for task done successfully without any error. But when i login with the user of that group. Task not show in the user my task.

1) I have manager group. 
2) There are manager user name mngr etc in it.
3) Below are my files please provide solution.
```

**below are my code for group in model**

```
            <mandatory-aspects>
                <aspect>bpm:groupAssignee</aspect>
            </mandatory-aspects>
```

**below are my code for web config**

```
<show-association name="bpm:groupAssignee" display-labelid="iabookwf_pm" />
```

**below are my code for the proccess defination**

```
<swimlane name="pmuser">
<assignment class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.AlfrescoAssignment">
                     <pooledactors>#{bpm_groupAssignee}</pooledactors>
            </assignment>
</swimlane >
```

My requirement is to assign task to group manager and then He will assign task to engineer.

The task is successful for simple one user assignment but It is not work for group.

Please find Below are my files for workflow which use in my custom workflow.

1   pm_taskModel.xml
    ----------------

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <model name="iabookwf:BookWFModel" xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0">
        <imports>
            <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d" />
            <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0" prefix="bpm" />
            <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm" />
        </imports>
        <namespaces>
            <namespace uri="http://www.infoaxon.com/book/models/workflow/1.0" prefix="iabookwf" />
        </namespaces>
        <constraints>
        <constraint name="iabookwf:department" type="LIST">
            <parameter name="allowedValues">
                <list>
                    <value>Java</value>
                    <value>Mobile</value>
                    <value>Php</value>
                </list>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="caseSensitive">
            <value>true</value>
            </parameter>
    </constraint>
    </constraints>
        <types>
            <type name="iabookwf:startTask">
                <title>Project Start</title>
                <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
                <properties>
                <property name="iabookwf:department">
                        <title>Department name</title>
                        <type>d:text</type>
                        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint ref="iabookwf:department" />
                        </constraints>
                    </property> 
                     <property name="iabookwf:Attachments">
                   <type>d:content</type>
                </property>
                    </properties>

                <mandatory-aspects>
                    <aspect>bpm:groupAssignee</aspect>
                </mandatory-aspects>
            </type>
            <type name="iabookwf:createRequirementTask">
                <parent>bpm:workflowTask</parent>
                <properties>
                    <property name="iabookwf:clientName">
                        <title>Client Name</title>
                        <type>d:text</type>
                        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    </property>
                    <property name="iabookwf:projectName">
                        <title>Project Name</title>
                        <type>d:text</type>
                        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    </property>
                    <property name="iabookwf:budget">
                        <title>Project Estimated Budget</title>
                        <type>d:double</type>
                        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    </property>

                </properties>
                <overrides>
                    <property name="bpm:packageActionGroup">
                        <default>add_package_item_actions</default>
                    </property>
                    <property name="bpm:packageItemActionGroup">
                        <default>edit_package_item_actions</default>
                    </property>
                </overrides>
                <mandatory-aspects>
                    <aspect>bpm:assignee</aspect>
                </mandatory-aspects>
            </type>

            <type name="iabookwf:reviewRequirementTask">
                <parent>bpm:workflowTask</parent>
                    <overrides>
                    <property name="bpm:packageActionGroup">
                        <default>add_package_item_actions</default>
                    </property>
                    <property name="bpm:packageItemActionGroup">
                        <default>edit_package_item_actions</default>
                    </property>
                </overrides>
                <mandatory-aspects>
                    <aspect>bpm:assignee</aspect>
                </mandatory-aspects>
            </type>

            <type name="iabookwf:createProjectSizingTask">
                <parent>bpm:workflowTask</parent>
                <properties>
                    <property name="iabookwf:estimatedhours">
                        <title>Estimated in Hours</title>
                        <type>d:int</type>
                        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    </property>
                    <property name="iabookwf:technologystack">
                        <title>Technology stack detail</title>
                        <type>d:text</type>
                        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    </property>
                        <property name="iabookwf:riskinvolvement">
                        <title>Risk involvement detail</title>
                        <type>d:text</type>
                        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                    <overrides>
                    <property name="bpm:packageActionGroup">
                        <default>add_package_item_actions</default>
                    </property>
                    <property name="bpm:packageItemActionGroup">
                        <default>edit_package_item_actions</default>
                    </property>
                </overrides>
                <mandatory-aspects>
                    <aspect>bpm:assignee</aspect>
                </mandatory-aspects>
            </type>
            <type name="iabookwf:createProjectPlanTask">
                <parent>bpm:workflowTask</parent>
                <properties>
                    <property name="iabookwf:startDate">
                        <title>Proposed Start Date</title>
                        <type>d:date</type>
                        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    </property>
                    <property name="iabookwf:endDate">
                        <title>Proposed End Date</title>
                        <type>d:date</type>
                        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    </property>
                    <property name="iabookwf:releaseDate">
                        <title>Proposed Final Release Date</title>
                        <type>d:date</type>
                        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                            <overrides>
                    <property name="bpm:packageActionGroup">
                        <default>add_package_item_actions</default>
                    </property>
                    <property name="bpm:packageItemActionGroup">
                        <default>edit_package_item_actions</default>
                    </property>
                </overrides>
                <mandatory-aspects>
                    <aspect>bpm:assignee</aspect>
                </mandatory-aspects>
            </type>
            <type name="iabookwf:kickOffDevelopmentTask">
                <parent>bpm:workflowTask</parent>
                <properties>
                    <property name="iabookwf:projectTeam">
                        <title>Finalized Project Team</title>
                        <type>d:text</type>
                        <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                        <multiple>true</multiple>
                    </property>
                    <property name="iabookwf:projectEnvDone">
                        <title>Project Environment setup Done?</title>
                        <type>d:boolean</type>
                        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                <overrides>
                    <property name="bpm:packageActionGroup">
                        <default>add_package_item_actions</default>
                    </property>
                    <property name="bpm:packageItemActionGroup">
                        <default>edit_package_item_actions</default>
                    </property>
                </overrides>
                <mandatory-aspects>
                    <aspect>bpm:assignee</aspect>
                </mandatory-aspects>
            </type>
        </types>
    </model>

    **web-client-config-custom.xml**
    --------------------------------

    <alfresco-config>

        <!-- Example of overriding the from email address -->
        <config>
            <client>
                <from-email-address>someone@your-domain.com</from-email-address>
                <search-max-results>100</search-max-results>
            </client>
        </config>

        <!-- Example of adding languages to the list in the login page -->
        <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Languages">
            <languages>
                <language locale="ca_ES">Catalan</language>
                <language locale="hr_HR">Croatian</language>
                <language locale="cs_CZ">Czech</language>
                <language locale="da_DK">Danish</language>
                <language locale="de_DE">German</language>
                <language locale="es_ES">Spanish</language>
                <language locale="el_GR">Greek</language>
                <language locale="fi_FI">Finnish</language>
                <language locale="fr_FR">French</language>
                <language locale="it_IT">Italian</language>
                <language locale="ja_JP">Japanese</language>
                <language locale="du_NL">Dutch</language>
                <language locale="pl_PL">Polish</language>
                <language locale="pt_PT">Portuguese</language>
                <language locale="pt_BR">Portuguese (Brazilian)</language>
                <language locale="ru_RU">Russian</language>
                <language locale="sv_SV">Swedish</language>
                <language locale="tr_TR">Turkish</language>
                <language locale="zh_CN">Simplified Chinese</language>
            </languages>
        </config>

        <config evaluator="node-type" condition="iabookwf:startTask"
            replace="true">
            <property-sheet>
                <separator name="sep1" display-label-id="general"
                    component-generator="HeaderSeparatorGenerator" />
                <show-property name="bpm:workflowDescription"
                    componentgenerator="TextAreaGenerator" />
                <show-property name="bpm:workflowPriority" />
                <show-property name="bpm:workflowDueDate" />
                <show-property name="iabookwf:department" />
                <show-property name="iabookwf:Attachments" />
                <show-association name="bpm:groupAssignee" display-labelid="iabookwf_pm" />
                <show-association name="iabookwf:aspect_file_relate" display-labelid="iabookwf_pm" />
            </property-sheet>
        </config>
        <config evaluator="node-type" condition="iabookwf:createRequirementTask"
            replace="true">
            <property-sheet>
                <separator name="sep1" display-label-id="general"
                    componentgenerator="HeaderSeparatorGenerator" />
                <show-property name="iabookwf:clientName" />
                <show-property name="iabookwf:projectName" />
                <show-property name="iabookwf:budget" />
                <show-property name="iabookwf:department" />
                <separator name="sep2" display-label-id="iabookwf_pm_header"
                    component-generator="HeaderSeparatorGenerator" />
                <show-association name="bpm:groupAssignee" display-labelid="iabookwf_pm" />
            </property-sheet>
        </config>
        <config evaluator="node-type" condition="iabookwf:createProjectSizingTask"
            replace="true">
            <property-sheet>
                <separator name="sep1" display-label-id="general"
                    componentgenerator="HeaderSeparatorGenerator" />
                <show-property name="iabookwf:estimatedhours" />
                <show-property name="iabookwf:technologystack" componentgenerator="TextAreaGenerator" />
                <show-property name="iabookwf:riskinvolvement" componentgenerator="TextAreaGenerator" />
                <separator name="sep2" display-label-id="iabookwf_pm_header"
                    component-generator="HeaderSeparatorGenerator" />
                <show-association name="bpm:assignee"
                    display-labelid="iabookwf_pm" />
            </property-sheet>
        </config>
        <config evaluator="node-type" condition="iabookwf:createProjectPlanTask"
            replace="true">
            <property-sheet>
                <separator name="sep1" display-label-id="general"
                    componentgenerator="HeaderSeparatorGenerator" />
                <show-property name="iabookwf:startDate" />
                <show-property name="iabookwf:endDate" />
                <show-property name="iabookwf:releaseDate" />
                <separator name="sep2" display-label-id="iabookwf_pm_header"
                    component-generator="HeaderSeparatorGenerator" />
                <show-association name="bpm:assignee"
                    display-labelid="iabookwf_pm" />
            </property-sheet>
        </config>
        <config evaluator="node-type" condition="iabookwf:kickOffDevelopmentTask"
            replace="true">
            <property-sheet>
                <separator name="sep1" display-label-id="general"
                    componentgenerator="HeaderSeparatorGenerator" />
                <show-property name="iabookwf:projectTeam" />
                <show-property name="iabookwf:projectEnvDone" />
                <separator name="sep2" display-label-id="iabookwf_pm_header"
                    component-generator="HeaderSeparatorGenerator" />
                <show-association name="bpm:assignee"
                    display-labelid="iabookwf_pm" />
            </property-sheet>
        </config>
        <config evaluator="node-type" condition="wfag:submitAdhocGroupTask" replace="true">
          <property-sheet>
             <separator name="sep1" display-label-id="general" component-generator="HeaderSeparatorGenerator" />
             <show-property name="bpm:workflowDescription" component-generator="TextAreaGenerator" />
             <show-property name="bpm:workflowPriority" display-label-id="wf_adhoc_priority" />
             <show-property name="bpm:workflowDueDate" display-label-id="wf_adhoc_due_date" />
             <show-property name="wfag:notifyMe" />
             <separator name="sep2" display-label-id="user_filter_user" component-generator="HeaderSeparatorGenerator" />
             <show-association name="bpm:groupAssignee" display-label-id="wf_adhoc_assign_to" />
          </property-sheet>


      </config>

    </alfresco-config>



    **pm_proccessdefination.xml**
    -------------------------

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <process-definition xmlns="urn:jbpm.org:jpdl-3.1"   name="iabookwf:pmprocess">
        <swimlane name="initiator" />
        <swimlane name="pmuser1">
          <assignment actor-id="#{bpm_assignee.properties['cm:userName']}"/>
      </swimlane>
        <swimlane name="pmuser">
        <assignment class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.AlfrescoAssignment">
                             <pooledactors>#{bpm_groupAssignee}</pooledactors>
                    </assignment>
        </swimlane >            


        <start-state name="start">
            <task name="iabookwf:startTask" swimlane="initiator" />
            <transition name="" to="submitRequirement" />

        </start-state>
        <task-node name="submitRequirement">
            <task name="iabookwf:createRequirementTask" swimlane="pmuser">

                <event type="task-create">
                    <script>
                        if (bpm_workflowDueDate != void) taskInstance.dueDate = bpm_workflowDueDate;
                        if (bpm_workflowPriority != void) taskInstance.priority = bpm_workflowPriority;
                    </script>
                </event>
            </task>
            <transition name="Submit Requirements" to="createProjectSizing" />
        </task-node>
        <task-node name="reviewRequirement">
            <task name="iabookwf:reviewRequirementTask" swimlane="pmuser">
                <event type="task-create">
                    <script>
                        if (bpm_workflowDueDate != void) taskInstance.dueDate = bpm_workflowDueDate;
                        if (bpm_workflowPriority != void) taskInstance.priority = bpm_workflowPriority;
                    </script>
                </event>
            </task>
            <transition name="Approve Requirements" to="createProjectSizing" />
            <transition name="Reject Requirements" to="submitRequirement" />
        </task-node>
        <task-node name="createProjectSizing">
            <task name="iabookwf:createProjectSizingTask" swimlane="pmuser1">
                <event type="task-create">
                    <script>
                        if (bpm_workflowDueDate != void) taskInstance.dueDate = bpm_workflowDueDate;
                        if (bpm_workflowPriority != void) taskInstance.priority = bpm_workflowPriority;
                    </script>
                </event>
            </task>
            <transition name="Submit Project Sizing" to="createProjectPlan" />
        </task-node>
        <task-node name="createProjectPlan">
            <task name="iabookwf:createProjectPlanTask" swimlane="pmuser">
                <event type="task-create">
                    <script>
                        if (bpm_workflowDueDate != void) taskInstance.dueDate = bpm_workflowDueDate;
                        if (bpm_workflowPriority != void) taskInstance.priority = bpm_workflowPriority;
                    </script>
                </event>
            </task>
            <transition name="Submit Project Plan" to="kickOffDevelopment" />
        </task-node>
        <task-node name="kickOffDevelopment">
            <task name="iabookwf:kickOffDevelopmentTask" swimlane="initiator">
                <event type="task-create">
                    <script>
                        if (bpm_workflowDueDate != void) taskInstance.dueDate = bpm_workflowDueDate;
                        if (bpm_workflowPriority != void) taskInstance.priority = bpm_workflowPriority;
                    </script>
                </event>
            </task>
            <transition name="Kick Off Development" to="end" />
        </task-node>
        <end-state name="end" />
    </process-definition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying in **alfrseco explorer** you need to add **"pooled-task" dashlet** on dashboard of users because all pooled tasks are visible only there.

Also, I do not see process-definition file. I assume you have already added proper entry for that task where as a swimlane you need to specify "pmuser".

Comment: Thanks It works fine. I seen previously in the my task not in my pooled task.